# eclipse ee servlet tomcat doPost http405

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, tomcat7, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to go a post from HTML to Java Servlet using eclipse ee and tomcat starting the server through eclipse.
But I am getting:
HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="AddHost">
Host name : <input name="hostname" type="text"><br>
Genre : <input name="genre" type="text" ><br>
<input type="submit" value="add host">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the servlet:

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;
@WebServlet("/AddHost")
public class Addhost extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost(HttpServletResponse res,HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException{
        String hostname = req.getParameter("hostname");
        String genre = req.getParameter("genre");


    }
    public void doGet(HttpServletResponse res,HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException{
        doPost(res,req);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used bad signature of method doPost and instead of [overriding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding), you are [overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overloading)

From [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) HttpServlet contains:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
```

So you should change this:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletResponse res,HttpServletRequest req)
```

to this:

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
```

@Override annotation is not necessary but strongly recommended to avoid such mistakes.

**edited:**
I added override annotation like mth suggested

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize the params needed to be in that order. Is there a reason for this? I will accept when it lets me.

Comment: Yes, order does matter. In Java we can have few methods with the same name but with different order, amount, type of parameters. Check my update and overloading link

Comment: That's why adding @Override is helpful - the compiler will catch it when you're not actually overriding, but overloading by mistake. And of course, using the "override method" feature of your IDE of choice helps a lot too (since the IDE will create the correct skeleton method for you)